# Add libraries after create binary Cx_Freeze Python

Tags: python, import, cx-freeze

I have a piece of code that dinamically import some library and use it. It works perfct.
The problem is that I am using Cx_Freeze to convert the python code to exe. It works fine but I need to add some libraries after I create the exe file.

When I create the exe file some libraries are saved in a zip file. If I need to add some extra library after create the exe file where must I place this library? What files must I have to place? Just in a case imagine that I want to add the package/library win32gui. How must I do it?
In resume:
I have my .exe code that has something like that:

```
__import__("module.py", fromlist=["main"])
```

And module.py has something like that:

```
import win32gui
main():
#Something else
```

Because win32gui package is not included in the .exe libraries there is a error

> "No module named win32gui"

Where and what may I to add to get it work??

If you need more info please just say it.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You can tell cx_Freeze to include `win32gui` when you freeze it. See [the docs](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
__import__("module", fromlist=["main"])
from module import win32gui
```

Comment: I think that you did not understand the question. I need to add te win32gui package to somewhere in order to the executable could be able to use it. Do you understand me?